# How to deploy test app on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I want to know how to deploy test app on iPhone 4.3.2. with XCode 4.3 but without buying a licence.

I have jailbreak on it and installed AppSync4.0+

The reason why I ask this is because I am porting an app from Qt and I want to see it how it behaves under iOS.

I have been using Qt4iOS and got everything build when using simulator. 
Now I want to see it on my device.

When I try it I got some key chain error.

Provide me with some links or ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... everything is possible. It's about the effort needed. And the effort for this can be very low. Especially because your device is are already jailbroken.

1. You'll need to change Xcode's code signing for building for an device. Instructions can be found here: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Xcode#Developing_without_Provisioning_Profile
   (better save copies of the original files). Since Xcode 4.3 doesn't use the /Developer folder any more you'll have to edit the files inside the Xcode.app (./Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/...)
2. Build your app for the device. Make sure the target isn't a fat binary (instead just build an ARMv6 executable) or it won't work on your device if pseudo-signed with ldid.
3. Find the .app bundle for your app
4. Copy the .app bundle to /Applications/ (not /var/mobile/Applications!!!) (for example via ssh). Make sure the permissions of your executable are set to 755. Reboot or respring and if you did everything correctly you'll be able to launch and test your app.

Have fun!

Comment: I followed your instructions, however, my app icon was not showing up on the device even after I changed the permissions to 775 and the owner to root:wheel. It took a full reboot to get the app to show up. I figured I would post here in case others were scratching their heads.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue.

No matter how hard we try to apply any trick in order to test the app on real device without license, the bottom line is that **you can't do it**.

You must register with apple by paying $99 and thereafter you can set the device to your real device within XCode before running the app.

Note that it's quite a task to create *.api file even after you are registered with Apple.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I have been searching on the internet and there are some efforts towards that achievement, if I found something I'll let you know

Answer (score -2):

Simple: Spend $99 for the iOS developer program.

I'm sure it is much more expensive to waste your time trying to find another way around.

Comment: you can always do it :) just depends on effort that you put in :)

Comment: I didn't say it's impossible. Possibly just a waste of time. Instead of doing this you could be productive and spend time on more important things.

Comment: Not sure why I received a downvote after like 2 years. If you want a proper answer, and you are taking this any serious, spend a few bucks. You are wasting so much more time (and if you are working for someone, their money) and trying to find another way around code signing, which will only lead to more waste of time afterwards. Go Android if you want more "freedom".