# The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid IOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I try to test my app on my jailbroken 5s I keep getting this error for some reason, it just started happening as well... I was able to test on my apps on my device this morning but now it doesn't work, and yes I tried restarting xCode.

Error message:

> The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid. Please
>   verify that your device’s clock is properly set, and that your signing
>   certificate is not expired. (0xE8008018).

My device time is set to automatic so I don't see how it could be incorrect, and the certificate is still valid, I just made a new one...

Please don't tell me I need to pay the 99 dollar developer fee to do this. I am jailbroken and I will not do this, nor will I install app sync as I didn't need it installed before. I have already created a self signing certificate and everything, even edited all the plist files and changed the build settings in my app, nothing works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deploy test app on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294960/how-to-deploy-test-app-on-iphone)

Comment: I want to know how to deploy test app on iPhone 4.3.2. with XCode 4.3, I said iPhone 5s on IOS 7.....

Comment: The instructions should be similar.

Comment: no kidded....I already did all of that...they all say to change the plist files and add a self signing certificate.... all of which I have already done...this problem is more advanced then you all think it is...

Answer (score -2):

Did you try to reverify the device in Xcode? If not try that. Else something tells me the system discovered your self made certificate.

Answer (score -2):

You can't use self-signed certificates with Xcode to my knowledge. You must use an Apple-issued certificate to publish using Xcode. There are special ways to install self-signed apps on jailbroken phones, and Xcode isn't one of them. In theory, you could modify the Xcode project's build procedure to use this special method, but it really isn't worth the hassle in my opinion. If $99 is honestly too much for you to have access to Apple's awesome developer community, then Android will always accept new developers. Just remember that $99 is *not much money* for most in the developed world, and if you own a Mac and an iPhone (or several) then you certainly can afford it, and it's definitely worth the money considering what it gets you.

Comment: I stated in my very question that it was just working, it obviously is possible, while I appreciate the input, your advice helps me in no way....

Comment: Apple doesn't want people to do this... it's likely a silent update to OS X, Xcode, or iOS broke compatibility.